# Как добавить разделительный слеш в середину строки

Tags: javascript

У меня есть массив строк:

```
['S', 'H', 'I', 'B', 'U', 'S', 'D', 'T']
```

Я уже разбил строку на отдельные буквы. Как мне перед "U" вставить разделительный слеш '/'?
Ну и потом склеить каждую букву в слово?

```
      allSymbols.map((currentLetter) => {
     let splitString = currentLetter.split('')
```

Comment: `'sdssddsdUsdssdsd'.replace(/U/g, '/U')`

Comment: А нужно каждую `U` заменить на `/U` или один конкретный?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если продолжать использовать ваш способ, то можно так:

```js
let chars = ['S', 'H', 'I', 'B', 'U', 'S', 'D', 'T']

chars = chars.map(e => e === 'U' ? '/U' : e)

console.log(chars)
```

#### Объяснение

Проходимся по массиву символов, если символ равен `U`, тогда вместо него возвращаем `/U`, а если это не так, то возвращаем тот же символ.

Можно ещё так:

```js
let chars = ['S', 'H', 'I', 'B', 'U', 'S', 'D', 'T']

chars = chars.map(e => e.replace(/U/, '/U'))

console.log(chars)
```

#### Объяснение

Также проходимся по всему массиву символов, заменяем символ `U` на `/U`, если такой есть.

Или через цикл `for`:

```js
let chars = ['S', 'H', 'I', 'B', 'U', 'S', 'D', 'T']

for (let i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
  let char = chars[i]

  if(char === 'U') {
    chars[i] = '/U'
  }
}

console.log(chars)
```

#### Объяснение

Проходимся по массиву, если символ равен `U`, то тогда в массиве заменяем элемент на `/U`. Заметьте, я меняю именно сам элемент массива, а не переменную `char`, т.к. `char` временная и сохраняется только в цикле, а вот если заменять элемент массива, тогда сама изменённая строка в массиве сохранится.

---

Каждый из массивов которые мы изменили можно соединить в одну строку методом `join`, вот так:

```js
let chars = ['S', 'H', 'I', 'B', 'U', 'S', 'D', 'T']

chars = chars.map(e => e === 'U' ? '/U' : e)

console.log(chars.join(''))
```

#### Уточнение

В методе `join`, я указываю пустую строку для того, чтобы массив объединился без лишних символом, т.к. если ничего не указывать в аргументы, то `join` по стандарту выбирает `,` как символ для объединения элементов массива.

Answer (score 1):

Если необходимо добавить разделитель в середину строки используя методы **.split()** и **.join()**, то можно сделать следующим образом:

```js
const str1 = 'asdfghjk';
const str2 = 'asdfghjkl';

function addSep(str) {
  const s = str.split('');
  const avg = Math.round((str.length - 1) / 2);
  s[avg] = '/' + s[avg];
  return s.join('');
}

console.log(addSep(str1))
console.log(addSep(str2))
```

Если же переводить строку в массив для каких либо других целей нет смысла, то можно воспользоваться методом **.slice()**

```js
const str1 = 'asdfghjk';
const str2 = 'asdfghjkl';

function repStr(str) {
  const avg = Math.round((str.length - 1) / 2);
  return str.slice(0, avg) + '/' + str.slice(avg)
}

console.log(repStr(str1))
console.log(repStr(str2))
```